# Read mixed data types from CSV row via tf.TextLineReader and tf.decode_csv

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to read more than just numeric features and labels from each line of the input CSV data file. My features and labels are both numeric, but I also want to use a date-like or string-like identifier for each line so I can refer back to the line after a random-shuffle batch read.

Since TensorFlow requires a `record_defaults` array that I pre-populate programmatically, how can I make TF read mixed types in one-line? If I pre-populate `record_defaults` with floats, I get an error for cells that contain dates/strings. If I pre-populate `record_defaults` with strings, with the view of casting the numeric parts later into floats, I get an error that TF doesn't support string-to-float casting.

The docs state:

*A list of Tensor objects with types from: float32, int32, int64, string. One tensor per column of the input record, with either a scalar default value for that column or empty if the column is required*

As per above, how can I specify 'empty' if I just want all columns as required and skip the whole defaults headache? And in that case how would TF know what data types to pick automatically for each cell? I have lots of columns, so it's not practical to write it out one-by-one as is done in the one example in the docs:

```
record_defaults = [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1]]
```

(I have hundreds of cells!)

My code looks something like this:

```
rDefaults = [[0.02] for row in range((300))]
reader = tf.TextLineReader(skip_header_lines=False)
_, csv_row = reader.read(filename_queue)
data = tf.decode_csv(csv_row, record_defaults=rDefaults)
dateLbl = tf.slice(data, [0], [TD]) # <- this is where I'm having the problem
features = tf.slice(data, [TD], [TS])
label = tf.slice(data, [TS], [TL])
```

Thanks for any input!

Comment: Can you use [string_to_number](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/array_ops/casting#string_to_number)? Then for any mixed-dtype columns I'd use a string input type.

Comment: Ah thanks for the suggestion. I wasn't aware of string_to_number and was relying on 'tf.cast()' instead, which gave me an error that converting from string to float is unsupported. 'string_to_number' seems to work well. There doesn't seem to be much overhead with this approach, but can I just confirm that the resultant float precision is kept as original, in case you know? I ran one test and the accuracy seems unchanged from prior experiments, so seems like should be OK. Also, the resultant strings seem to have b'' encoding, but seems like I can deal with that...

Comment: Well, you can [look at the implementations](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/string_to_number_op.cc). Looks like only float32 and int32 are supported, but as long as you're using one of those precision should be fine (and adding float64 or int64 would be just about the simplest feature request possible).